# Why is 'winreg' returning numbers?

Tags: python, firefox, winreg

I am writing a program to find the Firefox path.
I am using code from GitHub (don't mind that variables are named "chrome").

This program returns numbers:

```
def _find_chrome_win() -> Optional[str]:
    import winreg as reg
    reg_path = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe'
    chrome_path: Optional[str] = None

    for install_type in reg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:
        try:
            reg_key = reg.OpenKey(install_type, reg_path, 0, reg.KEY_READ)
            chrome_path = reg.QueryValue(reg_key, None)
            reg_key.Close()
            if not os.path.isfile(chrome_path):
                continue
        except WindowsError:
            chrome_path = None
        else:
            break

    print(chrome_path)

_find_chrome_win()
```

Comment: If I add the missing imports to support `isfile` and `Optional` (why do people leave imports out??), I get strings with your example.

Comment: Yes, it also works for me but with chrome, if I use it for firefox it returns numbers

Comment: Did you look in the registry to see what it is supposed to return?  I don't have firefox, but other things in my App Paths return paths.

Comment: yes if i ran it with vs code it returns path, but if i ran it with terminal the result is numbers

Comment: We don't have your environment, so there isn't enough information.  What is the *exact* value of the `<default>` for firefox in your registry?  You keep adding new information in your comments, but all the information to reproduce the issue should be in the question itself.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

Comment: In current user or local machine or both?  And what version of Python is running in VS code vs. the terminal.  Add a `import sys; print(sys.version)` to your script.  And if chrome works and firefox doesn't, are there any differences in the registry?

Comment: oh, sorry it seems there are folder with the same name but without spaces, sorry for wasting your time

Comment: If you want i can give thank and upvote

Comment: No need.  Question can be deleted its not really useful to others.